# ASP.NET pre-compile vs. pre-load

Tags: asp.net, performance, preloading

Does enabling preload for an ASP.NET website under IIS (7.5 and above) mean the site will get precompiled (via aspnet_compiler) once IIS starts or these considered two separate things?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things, but they are related. [PreLoad](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/11/iis-8-whats-new-website-settings/) simulates a user request after the website is made available by IIS, and it initializes it for faster response for subsequent requests. Now, if the website is already compiled, it might not have a big performance boost, but if the website is not yet compiled, then it will compile it using `aspnet_compiler.exe`.

This makes the website load considerably faster for the first user request, so they don't encounter initialization delay.